# Sitecore Children & HasChildren throws Stackoverflow exception

Tags: glass-mapper

I am trying to access children property in my Glass Model type.

```
public partial class Section : GlassBase
{
    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Section_Link> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But it is throwing stackoverflow exception when I try to access the children

```
if (section.Children.Any())
```

Later I tried using the Sitecore API's as well

```
    var sectionTest = Sitecore.Context
        .Database.GetItem(new ID("{AC29FD56-28F4-434A-B1E2-36BA9BE7A84F}"));
    if (sectionTest.HasChildren)
```

It also resulted in the same error.

```
Exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

**Section_Link** is a normal Glass model class

Can someone help me with if I am doing something wrong here

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Hi there, can you please provide version of Glass Mapper and Sitecore that you are using?

Comment: Hi, I am using Sitecore 8.2 and Glass Mapper 4.3.4 versions

Comment: @Meghan Please edit your question to include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @Meghan please post exception from sitecore log

Comment: @AndreyBobrov I am unable to see any logs in Sitecore with respect to this error. It is breaking before logging anything is what I guess

Comment: @Meghan check windows event logs for application errors and find the exception

Comment: The fact that this is happening with the bare Sitecore APIs tells me this is probably an issue in custom code somewhere.  The fact that it happens during the 'GetChildren' call tells me you probably have a circular recursive lookup going on when resolving children or items.  I would recommend removing all custom pipeline code, and seeing if that fixes things.  If so, I would then add back each piece of custom code one by one, until the problem recurs.  The one that causes the issue is your culprit.